# Is there a way to parse checkbox responses from Google Form in Google Sheet using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Form with 2 questions, both questions have checkbox options that allow people to vote on 3 items from each question. After voting has concluded, I want to export the responses to Google Sheets to then count up the votes. How can I do this? As I'm sure you know, Google Sheets puts all selected checkbox options into 1 column.

People are tracked by their email addresses and can only vote once

Currently it looks like this
|email|, |item 1, item 2, item 3|

I want it like this
|email|, |item 1|, |item 2|, |item 3|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a script you could always use a simple formula for that.

```
=ArrayFormula({B2:B,IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(C2:C,",",1,1)))})
```

[image]